# Share a class variable across multiple processes in python

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing

I have a class variable declared as a list that I want to update from a method declared within that class. However since this method processes a large amount of data, I am using multiprocessing to invoke it and hence I need to put lock on the class variable before updating it. I am unable to figure out how to put such a lock and update the class variable. If it matters, I am only creating one object of the said class at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of python's GIL, multiprocessing can only be used whith completely separate tasks, and no shared memory.
But you still can make it happend by using multiprocessing shared Array/Value:

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

Now as you asked, you need to ensure that differents processes won't access the same variable at the same time, and use a `Lock`. Hopefuly, all the shared variable available in the `multiprocessing` module are paired with a Lock.

To access the lock :

```
num.acquire() # get the lock
# do stuff
num.release() # don't forget to release it
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the documentation. I have used the Manager object to share data between processes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) module (as opposed to multi*threading*, which is different), then unless I'm mistaken, the multiple processes forked don't share memory and each process would have its own copy of your class. This would mean that a lock would not be necessary, but it would also mean that the class attribute is not shared like you want it to be.

The multiprocessing module does offer [several ways](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) to allow communication between processes, including shared array objects. Perhaps this is what you're looking for.

Depending on what you're doing, you might also consider using the master-worker pattern, where you create a worker class with methods to manipulate your data, spawn several processes to run this class, and then dispatch datasets to the workers from your main process using the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) class from the multiprocessing module.